# Convert string into a future date with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a MongoDB database connected to my web app. In it, I have the following Schema:

```
const SubmitSchema = new Schema ({
  date: String,
});
```

Date is stored as a string, but is actually an integer. These integers range from 1-31, so for example, the entries may be '1', or '14', or '26'.

What I want to do with this string integer, is the following:

1. Pull the date from the database - complete
2. Convert the date into an integer using parseInt - complete
3. Turn the number into a date string - i.e, if the number in the database = 23, then turn the date string into (as a random example) - 23rd November 2020
4. Look at today's date, if before 23rd November 2020, keep the date as is, if todays date is the 23rd November 2020 or later, change it to 23rd December 2020

So, my question is - how do I do points 3 and 4. What is the best approach? I wish to do this with vanilla JavaScript in my React frontend.

I don't want to store this date in my database... It seems overkill, just convert the string into that format for the user.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

EDIT: Just realised the task list looked horrible, so edited..

Comment: I would recommend to use  moment library to operate on date obj

Comment: I actually use Moment already for something else. I don't think it's suitable here though, as I only have a number, not a date string.